# NullPointerException for LinkedList queue array

Tags: java, queue, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I am getting a weird NullPointerExcpetion in line 20:

```
regs[Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]) - 1].add(line.poll());
```

I do not know what has caused this. Can someone please help me fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class shoppay
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shoppay.in"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("shoppay.out")));
    Queue<Integer> line = new LinkedList <Integer>();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine());
    String str;
    LinkedList<Integer>[] regs = (LinkedList<Integer>[]) new LinkedList[num];

    while ((str = f.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (str.charAt(0) == 'C')
            line.add(Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]));
        else
            regs[Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]) - 1].add(line.poll());
    }

    out.close();
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Also, I am getting a warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from java.util.LinkedList[] to java.util.LinkedList[]

Does this have something to do with the error?

Edit: Input is just a string of lines. First line is a number, and the rest are either "C" or "R" followed by a number. Also, I need a queue for regs.

Comment: The `Type Safety` warning is unrelated to the `NullPointerException`. The `Type Safety` exception likely has to do with the type of the `LinkedList` being cast instead of set to Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create an array of generic lists. For technical reasons, it doesn't really work cleanly. It's much better to use a list of lists:

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shoppay.in"));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("shoppay.out")));
Queue<Integer> line = new LinkedList <Integer>();
int num = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine()); // not needed
String str;
List<List<Integer>> regs = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(num);

for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    regs.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
}

while ((str = f.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'C')
        line.add(Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]));
    else
        regs.get(Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]) - 1).add(line.poll());
}
```

As a side issue, is there any reason you're using LinkedList for `regs` instead of `ArrayList`?

Comment: I just need a queue for regs, so I used LinkedList. Also, I got an IndexOutOfBoundsException when running this.

Comment: @DannyArsenic Perhaps I didn't understand your original code, but I think you were indexing into `regs` by the same expression I'm using in the call to `get`. I believe that if you had solved the NullPointerException problem, then you would have the same IndexOutOfBoundsException with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your input looks like, I can only guess at the cause of the error. I would guess that when you split the String, you are splitting something that results in array of size 1. Are you aware that this will be zero-indexed? This means that the first position in the array is `0` and the second is `1` and so forth. If you did intend to select the second item in the list, then ensure that your input will always split into at least 2 items.

Comment: He probably wouldn't want the first element as he already checks if it starts with a character. Ensuring that it contains at least 2 items is good advice of course.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. I changed my mind and decided to use an array. (int[]) I guess it worked fine.